# Extract only the numbers that are not around letters?

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to match only the pure numbers in a string like:

```
1,100,1000,c4,c5,c6,c10,c100
```

And I have tried this：

```
[^c]\d+
```

And it still included the sub-strings starting with 'c'.

I have also tried this:

```
[^c\d+]\d+
```

And it excluded those sub-strings starting with 'c' but the matched was like `,100`, which was not what I want either.

What could be the solution?

Comment: if you dont want the `,` just `split` it first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try negative lookbehind:

```
(?<![a-z0-9])\d+
```